# How to know the current class inside shared concern

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activesupport-concern

I have 3 models that each have an hstore column that includes, potentially, the same 4 attributes.  The code for facilitating these hstore attributes includes the store_accessor call, a method used to share these hstore attributes with strong params, and a couple other methods.

Very similar, if not exact, code exists in 3 different classes.

The store_accessor call is actually wrapped inside a loop that loops through a class method which returns a list of attribute names (which may or may not be unique for each of the 3 models).

```
class Foo

  def self.array_of_attrs
    %w(one two three)
  end

  Foo.array_of_attrs.each do |a|
    ...
    store_accessor :hstore_col_name, "#{ a }_yada_yada".to_sym
  end
```

simple enough..  However, I would like to move all this code to a concern (boo, hiss) and share that concern with each of the 3 affected classes.  The problem I have encountered is...I do not know which class is currently calling the concern.  In other words, Foo, is not Foo...it is whichever of the 3 classes is using the concern.

Inside the concern, how could I use the current class?  In this example, how would I dynamically call the current class instead of calling the Foo class?

Comment: Have you tried `self.class`?

Comment: I have...but, self is the class.  Calling self on a class method is like calling self.self.xyz_method.  I think, maybe, sort of...   Like, even if you wanted to call a class method inside the class you can't use self...you'd have to call the class from inside itself.  Which I find confusing, too.

Comment: Have you tried it with the code in a concern, not in the class? BTW, concern (boo, hiss), indeed.

Comment: I have...  Perhaps, I need another DRY approach.  One that doesnt use concerns.

Comment: I find your question a bit confusig too, have you tried just `self` (not `self.class`)? It would be usefull if you include the concern in your question and which classes include it. Along with an instance of `Foo` trying to run the function. Maybe we can find another DRY aproach.

Comment: I have tried self.  But, a class method is defined as def self.xyz_method.  You can not call this method using self, as self would be a class object.  You would call this method using Foo.xyz_method.  So, the question becomes...what if you had multiple classes with a class method named xyz_method and you wanted to share that method between those classes, but needed a way to call the method from the class dynamically.  Not sure that makes it any more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use [`included`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.1/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html#method-i-included) in a concern the including class is passed as an argument to the block:

```
module Bar
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do |base|
    base.array_of_attrs.each do |a|
     # ...
     store_accessor :hstore_col_name, "#{ a }_yada_yada".to_sym
    end
  end
end

class Foo < ApplicationRecord
  include Bar
end
```

And yes, you should be using `included` since accessors are declared in the class context.

Remember that this is just a syntactic sugar for:

```
module Baz
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks max!  I did not know I could pass the class as an argument to the included block.  That set me straight.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

```
module Foo
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do

      def self.some_method
        array_of_attrs.each do |a|
          ...
          store_accessor :hstore_col_name, "#{ a }_yada_yada".to_sym
        end
      end

    end
  end
end

class Model < ApplicationRecord
  include Foo

  def self.array_of_attrs
    %w(one two three)
  end
end

Model.some_method
```